# Dynamically adding user to a loopback Role

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have been studying the loopback / Strongloop documentation and it is not clear to me that it is possible to dynamically add a new user to a role (i.e. add a user to role via role-mapping), that is, without the need to restart the API.

Can anyone confirm one way or the other? (ideally, but not necessarily, pointing me to some documentation or example to confirm or not that this is doable).

Thanks much.

Comment: How did it go with strongloop? Was it comfortable, considering lack of docs/tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

You can create rolemappings for users in strongloop with something like this -

```
Role.find({where: {name: roleName}}, function(err, role) {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}

        RoleMapping.create({
          principalType: "USER",
          principalId: userId,
          roleId: role.id
        }, function(err, roleMapping) {

          if (err) {return console.log(err);}

          console.log('User assigned RoleID ' + role.id + ' (' + ctx.instance.type + ')');

        }):

      });
```

Now you have to execute this code either in the `after save` operation hook or if you have defined any remote method for creating a user you will have to look for a after remote hook and do this because you would need the `id` of the user which would be available only after user is saved in database

If you are using some operation hooks then it would be something like this -

```
user.observe('after save', function function_name(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    if(ctx.isNewInstance) {

      // look up role based on type
      //
      Role.find({where: {name: 'role-name'}}, function(err, role) {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}

        RoleMapping.create({
          principalType: "USER",
          principalId: ctx.instance.id,
          roleId: role.id
        }, function(err, roleMapping) {

          if (err) {return console.log(err);}

          console.log('User assigned RoleID ' + role.id + ' (' + ctx.instance.type + ')');

        }):

      });

    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks much for this answer.  Fits the bill perfectly, however, it seems that I am too low on the rung to up-vote it.  Cheers.

Comment: @digerati-stratagies i rung up the bell.