# Loopback - Add user is not adding the roleMapping data

Tags: node.js, loopback

What is the best practice to add the data in roleMapping corresponding to the user while adding the user.

1) Set the relation in the model-config, whether it will add the roleMapping data?

2) In the after save hook of user, need to manually add the roleMapping like referred here: [Link][1].

[1]: [Dynamically adding user to a loopback Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845480/dynamically-adding-user-to-a-loopback-role), like below:

```
user.observe('after save', function function_name(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    if(ctx.isNewInstance) {

      // look up role based on type
      //
      Role.find({where: {name: 'role-name'}}, function(err, role) {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}

        RoleMapping.create({
          principalType: "USER",
          principalId: ctx.instance.id,
          roleId: role.id
        }, function(err, roleMapping) {

          if (err) {return console.log(err);}

          console.log('User assigned RoleID ' + role.id + ' (' + ctx.instance.type + ')');

        }):

      });

}
```

}
  next();
});

Answer (score 0):

```
user.observe('after save', function function_name(ctx, next) {
if (ctx.instance) {
    if (ctx.isNewInstance) {
        // look up role based on type
        Role.find({
            where: {
                name: 'role-name'
            }
        }, function(err, role) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            role.principals.create({
                principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
                principalId: ctx.instance.id
            }, function(err, roleMapping) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                console.log('User assigned RoleID ' + role.id + ' (' + ctx.instance.type + ')');
            }):
        });
    }
}
next();
```

});

From my understanding of loopback, the User and Roles are connected through RoleMapping models. ie. User has many Roles through RoleMapping or viceversa.

What you have written can also be done like this.

In `principalType` you can specify any string that you want. If you give `RoleMapping.USER` it will show `USER` in the database.